# the limit $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sin(\arctan(\sin x))}{\sqrt{x} \sin 3x +x^2+ \arctan 5x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

a hint to start to find the limit of this
$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sin(\arctan(\sin x))}{\sqrt{x} \sin 3x +x^2+ \arctan 5x}$
without using L'Hospital rule

Comment: **Hint** Both $\sin u$ and $\arctan u$ have Maclaurin series $u + o(u)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\sin(\arctan(\sin x))=\frac{\sin (x)}{\sqrt{1+\sin ^2(x)}}$$ makes the problem much simpler.

Concerning the denominator, it behaves like $k x$ (I let you finding $k$).

Answer (score 0):

The numerator is like $x$,
since all the functions are
$x + O(x^3)$,
and the denominator is like
$5x$ since
$\sqrt{x}\sin(3x)$ 
is like $3x^{3/2}$
and this and $x^2$
are smaller than $x$.

The result is therefore
$\dfrac15$.